# Fetching dynamic data - remix run - storefrontapi - graphql

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, remix.run

I have having trouble trying to fetch dynamic data on Remix run and the shopify storefront api.  I am able to fetch all the products from the API but when I want to get the data of a specific product eg - when you click on one of the products I get the error

message: "Field 'product' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'",

Using the shopify graphql on the website my query works fine but as soon as i try and implement it on remix it does not work

```
export async function getProduct(slug: any):Promise<any> {
  const variable = {id: slug}
  const URL = `${domain}/api/2021-07/graphql.json`
  const query = `
  query GetProductsById($id: ID!) {

  product(id: $id) {
    title
     featuredImage {
       id
     }
  }
}
  `
  
  
  const options = {
    endpoint: URL,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": storefrontAccessToken,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variable })
  }
  
  try {
    const response: Response = await fetch(URL, options);
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
  
  
  } catch (error) {
  
    throw new Error("Products not fetched")
  }
  }
```

This is the error message

```
GET /products/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzY5NjQ2MDEzMjM2NjA=?_data=routes%2Fproducts%2F%24slug 200 - - 25.181 ms
[1] {
[1]   errors: [
[1]     {
[1]       message: "Field 'product' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'",
[1]       locations: [Array],
[1]       path: [Array],
[1]       extensions: [Object]
[1]     },
[1]     {
[1]       message: 'Variable $id is declared by GetProductsById but not used',
[1]       locations: [Array],
[1]       path: [Array],
[1]       extensions: [Object]
[1]     }
[1]   ]
[1] }
```

Does anyone haven idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two issues here:

1. `product` doesn't exist in the Storefront API version you're using ([`2021-07`](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2021-07/queries/product#examples-Retrieve_a_single_product)), that only got introduced in `2021-10`. If you can't upgrade you can use `node` instead, code example below.
2. Rename `variable` to `variables` in your request.

```
query getProductById($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Product {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the images from the storefront API - having the same issue?